# Merge two assosiative arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, merge

First array:

```
$Array['product'] = array('staff' => 'abc','services' => 0, 'products' => 100, 'total_sales' => 0)
```

Second array:

```
$Array['product'] = array('staff' => 'abc','services' => 150, 'products' => 0, 'total_sales' => 0)
```

I want the final result as:

```
$array['total'] = array('staff' => 'abc','services' => 150, 'products' => 100, 'total_sales' => 0)
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: *"I want ..."* - Is not a question. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74562692/edit) with your own attempts, including any errors you've encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$array['total'] = array_merge($Array['product1'], $Array['product2']);
```